# multiple where condition codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How can I convert this query to active record?

```
"UPDATE table_user 
 SET email = '$email', last_ip = '$last_ip' 
 where username = '$username' and status = '$status'";
```

I tried to convert the query above to:

```
$data = array('email' => $email, 'last_ip' => $ip);
$this->db->where('username',$username);
$this->db->update('table_user',$data);
```

How about using the where clausa status?

```
# must i write db->where two times like this?
$this->db->where('username',$username);
$this->db->where('status',$status);
```

I also tried this:

```
$this->db->where('username',$username,'status',$status);
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

you can use an array and pass the array.

```
Associative array method:
$array = array('name' => $name, 'title' => $title, 'status' => $status);

$this->db->where($array); 

// Produces: WHERE name = 'Joe' AND title = 'boss' AND status = 'active'
```

**Or if you want to do something other than = comparison**

```
$array = array('name !=' => $name, 'id <' => $id, 'date >' => $date);

$this->db->where($array);
```

Answer (score 18):

Yes, multiple calls to where() is a perfectly valid way to achieve this.

```
$this->db->where('username',$username);
$this->db->where('status',$status);
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Comment: although this is ONE way to achieve this. Its much easier to use an array of key,values

Comment: Useful to know, since you might need to extend a where clause after evaluating some condition.

Comment: This works perfectly in join also:             $this->db->where('TRIPSHEET_MAIN.id', $id);
            $this->db->where("CASH.tripsheet_id", $id);

Answer (score 2):

you can try this function for multi-purpose

```
function ManageData($table_name='',$condition=array(),$udata=array(),$is_insert=false){
$resultArr = array();
$ci = & get_instance();
if($condition && count($condition))
    $ci->db->where($condition);
if($is_insert)
{
    $ci->db->insert($table_name,$udata);
    return 0;
}
else
{
    $ci->db->update($table_name,$udata);
    return 1;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

`$wherecond = "( ( ( username ='" . $username . "' OR status='" . $status . "') AND (id='" . $id . "') ) )";
        $this->db->where($wherecond);`

> If you want to add AND and OR conditions at a time. this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$data = array(
               'email' =>$email,
               'last_ip' => $last_ip
            );

$where = array('username ' => $username , 'status ' => $status);
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->update('table_user ', $data);
```

Comment: Any idea how can I add a OR condition in this/

Answer (score 1):

it's late for this answer but i think maybe still can help, i try the both methods above, using two where conditions and the method with the array, none of those work for me i did several test and the condition was never getting executed, so i did a workaround, here is my code:

```
public function validateLogin($email, $password){
        $password = md5($password);
        $this->db->select("userID,email,password");
        $query = $this->db->get_where("users", array("email" => $email));
        $p = $query->row_array();

        if($query->num_rows() == 1 && $password == $p['password']){  
            return $query->row();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use both use array like :

```
$array = array('tlb_account.crid' =>$value , 'tlb_request.sign'=> 'FALSE' );
```

and direct assign like:

```
$this->db->where('tlb_account.crid' =>$value , 'tlb_request.sign'=> 'FALSE');
```

I wish help you.