# how can i use multiple where clause In codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

For my database query I have to use multiple where clause query in Codeigniter PHP. I wrote the code like this:

```
 $this->db->and_where_in('category_name,publication_status','home_headline_sub',1);
```

But this query shows database query error in browser. Then I wrote this query:

```
$this->db->where('category_name,publication_status','home_headline_sub',1);
```

But it still give error. Can anyone help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use Codeingiter user-guide everything is there

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple where condition codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538376/multiple-where-condition-codeigniter)

Comment: If you've found one of the answers helpful, please accept it and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain database clauses, so you would write it as

```
$this->db->where('category_name','case')->where('publication_status','case')->where('home_headline_sub','case');
```

This would generate a query's WHERE clause as

```
// WHERE category_name = 'case' AND publication_status = 'case' AND home_headline_sub = 'case'
```

Documentation here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#chaining

Answer (score 0):

you to use array in it.

```
$this->db->where(array('category_name'=>case,'publication_status'=>case,'home_headline_sub'=>case));
```

but I guess you want to check your value against three columns. you can use

```
$this->db->or_where(array('category_name'=>1,'publication_status'=>1,'home_headline_sub'=>1));
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
//The simple way
$this->db->where('foo_field', 'foo_value')
         ->where('bar_field', 'bar_value')
         ->where('more_field', 'more_value');

//using custom string
//if your sql is really a complex one you can simply write like these

$this->db->where("(foo_filed = 'foo_value') AND (bar_field = 'bar_value') AND (more_field = 'more_value')");

//or may be with something more complex like this
$this->db->where("(foo_filed = 'foo_value') AND ((bar_field = 'bar_value') OR (more_field = 'more_value'))");

//while using a custom string make sure you put them all in the "double quotation marks" and use no ,commas. It is all a single line. The braces are not necessary always but I like to use them.
```

[Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: how can i use this where clause with 'limit'. suppose i use limit '2'. how can i write code in model?

Comment: just like this
$this->db->where('foo', 'bar');
$this->db->limit(2);
they just have to be in the same method(function) in your model.

Comment: if i use 2 category name, both call in on where clause & if i want 2 content of each category (using limit 2)..how can i do that ? i write a code but there show 2 content for both category but i want 4 content..each category  has 2 content..

Comment: As long the contents are from the same table of your mysql database limit(2) should work just fine. something like this 
$this->db->select('foo, bar')->where('foo', 'f')->where('bar', 'b')->limit(2); $query=$this->db->get('table');  then you should get just the 4 contents you want. If they are from different tables you would have to join them. In that case limit(2) will work fine too.

Comment: public function select_all_content_2()
    {  
        
      $this->db->select('category_name');    
      $this->db->where('category_name','home_headline_left') 
              ->where('category_name', 'home_headline_right'); 
     $this->db->order_by('date_add','DESC'); 
     $this->db->limit ( 2 ); 
     $query_result = $this->db->get('content'); 
        $home_headline_left = $query_result->result(); 
        return $home_headline_left; 
    }.....here my code which write in model...but it nor works..after write this content doesn't show